# journalctl doesn't show logs of a snap

Tags: snap, systemd, systemd-journald

When I run a snap application in the terminal like this:

```bash
/usr/bin/snap run shadowsocks-rust.ssserver -c /etc/shadowsocks-rust/config.json
```

I see the logs:

```
2023-05-14T18:55:11.714373725+03:00 INFO  shadowsocks server 1.15.3 build 2023-03-12T16:38:32.068195882+00:00
2023-05-14T18:55:11.715955767+03:00 INFO  shadowsocks tcp server listening on 0.0.0.0:12345, inbound address 0.0.0.0:12345
```

But when I run the same as a systemd service:

```
[Unit]
Description=shadowsocks service
After=network-online.target

[Service]
User=myuser
ExecStart=/usr/bin/snap run shadowsocks-rust.ssserver -c /etc/shadowsocks-rust/config.json
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The only logs I see are from systemd (`journalctl -u shadowsocks.service`):

```
May 14 18:37:08 mypc systemd[1]: Started shadowsocks service.
```

Service status:

```bash
# systemctl status shadowsocks.service
● shadowsocks.service - shadowsocks service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/shadowsocks.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2023-05-14 18:37:08 MSK; 6s ago
   Main PID: 3453512 (ssserver)
      Tasks: 0 (limit: 9135)
     Memory: 32.0K
        CPU: 87ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/system-shadowsocks.slice/shadowsocks.service
             ‣ 3453512 /snap/shadowsocks-rust/443/bin/ssserver -c /etc/shadowsocks-rust/config.json
```

How can I make journalctl show logs of a snap running as a systemd service?

Comment: Here described the same problem, but no solution: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/systemd-services-running-snap-apps-fail-to-associate-journal-logs/26714